# Using IPython if set ArcGIS's python as default kernel in spyder?

Tags: arcpy, installation, spyder, ipython

i install anaconda first then set the arcgis python 2.7.8 win32 as interpreter just like
[Importing arcpy in Spyder](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/176879/importing-arcpy-in-spyder) said,but why i cannot open my IPython then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you set the arcpy paths correctly, but this is how I did to import arcpy into Spyder. To set the path of arcpy, go to `Tools -> PYTHONPATH Manager` and add the following paths:

1. C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcToolbox\Scripts
2. C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\arcpy
3. C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\bin

It will should be like this:

[image]

I could use IPython without any problem.

Comment: hi, ahmadhanb, really appreciate your kindly answer.  i successfully import arcpy into IPython following your guide although encountered another problem……
i install the gdal, add the path to windows environment variables then add its folder path (which is 'C:\program files(x86)\GDAL')into PYTHONPATH manager, but why can't i import the gdal in IPython.
Mysteriously, i import gdal in Console python successfully.
import gdalTraceback (most recent call last):……
thks again~

Comment: Hi bwbj, it is better to ask a new question regarding the problem of importing gdal. Following the policy of GIS SE, you should ask one question at a time. Since the original question was how to import arcpy into spyder and my instructions solved your problem, asking a new question here about the problem of importing gdal into spyder will confuse the community.