# Error attempting to Run ArcPy Script in Anaconda's Spyder

Tags: arcpy, installation, spyder

I'm attempting to switch over from running ArcPy scripts in Idle to running ArcPy scripts in Anaconda's Spyder GUI.

When I copy over the code and attempt to execute it, I get the following error:

```
File "C:\Program Files     (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
from _base import *
ImportError: No module named '_base'
```

Here is the attached code:

```
import os
import sys
import string
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")

workpath = "C:/workspace/gates/THRG/tmin_monthly_summaries/"
arcpy.env.workspace = workpath
tiffs = arcpy.ListRasters("*")
print (tiffs)
```

Comment: I have already done the follwing: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/194508/using-ipython-if-set-arcgiss-python-as-default-kernel-in-spyder?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: What is the full error message, including line number, from running the code that you presented?